# How do I change the path where Platformio is looking for the platformio.exe file?

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, path, exe, platformio

I am getting this error while trying to build in platformio. The terminal process failed to launch: Path to shell executable "c:\Users\aditi.DESKTOP-49PGKM5\Documents\Test1\platformio.exe" does not exist. Test1 is my cpp file. The path in quotation marks("") is not where the platformio.exe file is, but it is where the Test1 file.
But when I run the command c:\Users\aditi.DESKTOP-49PGKM5\Documents\Test1\platformio.exe run in powershell it works. How do I change the path that platformio is using to find the platformio.exe file?

I have tried reinstalling vscode, platformio, deleting the .platformio folder, adding the custom path in the Json settings file "platformio-ide.customPATH": "C:\Users\aditi.DESKTOP-49PGKM5\.platformio\penv\Scripts\platformio.exe" like this but no luck.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found several approaches on the internet because I was facing kind of the same behavior.

However, in the end it was just adding the folder with platformio.exe to path (expecting you are using Windows). Search for `environment variables` in your Windows search bar and add `C:\Users\<YOU>\.platformio\penv\Scripts` (or wherever the platformio.exe is on your system) to path.

Then restart VSCode and it should end up working.

Credits for that: https://community.platformio.org/t/build-fails-after-most-recent-updates/16351/8

Answer (score 0):

If the project is in your currently opened Workspace then you should find the project you are currently working on listed at the bottom center of the window just to the right of the terminal icon. Click on the current project and a drop down menu of all your projects will appear at the top of the window.  Select the project you wish to operate on and I think all will work for you. Random Nerds has a good free tutorial on how to use the PIO